# How to execute this list comprehension code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understanding this code, but so far I am unable to draw any logic. I've executed it to get the output, but still, I can't figure out. Here is the code:

```
lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)] 
for x in lst: 
    for y in x: 
       if y < 2: 
           print('*', end='')
```

I'm executing it from right-to-left, i.e starting from right-side loop "for r in range(3)". First, r will be "0" which will then be assigned to left-side loop "c for c in range(r)". After this point, I don't know how it will execute further.

Please if somebody can explain then it would be great.
Thanks/

Comment: Try it with `6` instead of `3` to see the pattern: https://repl.it/repls/HumbleOffensiveOrigin

Comment: @ sshashank124 Thanks. It is helpful. And clear now :) !! Trying with 6 makes it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]
```

The outer loop `[...] for r in range(3)]` will make a list of the results of the inner loop `[c for c in range(r)]` with `r` being 0, 1, and 2, in that order (the results of `range(3)`).

So the inner loop `[c for c in range(r)]` will give a list of each element of `range(r)`, which should give `[]`, `[0]`, and `[0, 1]`. So, final result is `[[], [0], [0, 1]]`

Notice that this is equivalent to the following:

```
lst = []
for r in range(3):
   lst.append([])         # since list comprehension in list comprehension
   for c in range(r):
        lst[-1].append(c) # -1 index is the last index in python
```

---

```
for x in lst: 
    for y in x: 
       if y < 2: 
           print('*', end='')
```

For every list in `lst`, for every element in that list, print `*` if it's less than 2. In other words, "For every individual element in the list"

Answer (score 1):

Nice answers have been posted. Not much to add to that. All I have to add is ... **print( ) is "one" of your best friends in programming**. If ever in doubt, print might give some clarity.

For example, for changing values (as @sshashank124 suggested) and doing print, lets you see what lst is. Once you know what lst is you can figure out what is happening as well as the downstream code.

```py
lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]
print(lst)

lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(4)]
print(lst)

lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(5)]
print(lst)

lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(6)]
print(lst)
```

This gives four outputs for values of 3,4,5 and 6 .. you can see the pattern

```py
[[], [0], [0, 1]]
[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Hope this gives some additional value to you, else I am sorry.

Comment: Many thanks for adding clarity. It is helpful and code is clear now :).